# Testing an AJAX POST using Rack::Test - how to pass in data?

Tags: ajax, rest, sinatra, rack-test

I'm using [Rack::Test](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test) to test my app and need to test the posting of data via AJAX.

My test looks like:

```
describe 'POST /user/' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  it 'must allow user registration with valid information' do
    post '/user', {
      username: 'test_reg',
      password: 'test_pass',
      email: 'test@testreg.co'
    }.to_json, {"CONTENT_TYPE" => 'application/json', "HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH" => "XMLHttpRequest"}
    last_response.must_be :ok?
    last_response.body.must_match 'test_reg has been saved'
  end
end
```

But at the server end it's not receiving the POSTed data.

I also tried just passing in the params hash without the `to_json` but that made no difference.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so my solution is a little weird and specific to the way I am triggering my JSON request in the first place, namely using `jQuery Validation` and `jQuery Forms` plugins on the client end.  `jQuery Forms` doesn't bundle the form fields into a stringified Hash as I'd expected, but sends the form fields via AJAX but as a classic URI encoded params string.  So by changing my test to the following, it now works fine.

```
describe 'POST /user/' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  it 'must allow user registration with valid information' do
    fields = {
      username: 'test_reg',
      password: 'test_pass',
      email: 'test@testreg.co'
    }
    post '/user', fields, {"HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH" => "XMLHttpRequest"}
    last_response.must_be :ok?
    last_response.body.must_match 'test_reg has been saved'
  end
end
```

Of course this is specific to the way the `jQuery Forms` plugin works and not at all how one would normally go about testing the POSTing of JSON data via AJAX. I hope this helps others.

Comment: Is that necessary? I was under the impression that if you drop the Content-Type and URI.encode_www_form that it would process the form as either JSON or Form-URL-Encoded automatically.

(You haven't mentioned here or in the question whether you tried without the third (ie. the hash) argument to post().)

Comment: Thanks @RobHoward, I altered my tests and you are right. I've updated my answer accordingly. I still need the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` param tho so the server knows it's an AJAX thing. Cheers D

Comment: THANK YOU. I was attempting to get a test case to work and it was failing because I could not figure out how to get it to send an xhr request (in Padrino with Minitest if that's any help).

adding the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header solved this!

Answer (score 4):

Your post endpoint must parse the posted JSON body itself, which I assume you already do. Can you post how your end point works, also the rack-test, rack,ruby and sinatra version numbers?  Please mention also how you test whether the server's receiving anything -- namely test mockup may confuse your detection.

```
    post '/user' do
       json_data = JSON.parse(request.body.read.to_s)
       # or # json_data = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
       ...
    end
```

Comment: Interesting. In my actual application code Sinatra's `params` variable gets populated automagically with the data coming in from the AJAX request, but when data is sent from the test I can extract it as you recommend, but `params` is not populated. Indeed when I add the `JSON.parse` line to my code I get a `JSON::ParserError`. This makes me suspect that issue is with the way the `jQuery forms` plugin's `ajaxSubmit` method is sending the data. Seems my error is not in the test after all. Thanks you've given me a line of enquiry to explore further.